# Switch from MySql driver to MariaDB driver for Jackrabbit

Tags: mysql, driver, mariadb, jackrabbit

```
Jackrabbit 2.6.4
MySQL 5.5
mariadb-java-client 1.5.5
mysql.connector.version 5.1.35
```

I have an app that uses `Jackrabbit` on a `MySQL` database. I am testing switching the `com.mysql.jdbc` driver in favour of the `org.mariadb.jdbc` driver.

So far, I have encountered no problems testing with simple node save/update/delete operations. My question is has anybody had any problems switching drivers whilst remaining on a `MySQL` database, primarily in the context of `Jackrabbit`? I'm wondering what else I can test before saying "it all works".

And before you ask "why aren't you switching the DB as well", that's next on my list.

Comment: Shouldn't the driver be switched _with_ the database which it supports?

Comment: According to the MariaDB site, it _does_ support MySQL.

Comment: It implements MySQL protocol, so of course it does support MySQL.  There are so far not a single example of a driver (no matter which language) that would support exclusively MariaDB, but not MySQL. MariaDB JDBC naturally also supports additions that are going to be added in MariaDB 10.2 (primarily for faster batch operations, which is already pretty fast in this driver, and for faster login)